# ruby on rails project pulling from an api trying to save bids from bids controller and display on the user show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, model-view-controller, controller

I'm accessing an api to pull the lowest price and event id and then based on the current lowest price you can place a bid I'm currently stuck at just creating a bid and saving it to the user show page I can manually enter the params on the event show page which triggers my create method on bid page which then all bids placed by a user should show up on a user show page because a user has many bids and bid belongs to a user below is a snippet from my event show page showing the ability to manually create a bid and save to the database

```
    <%= form_tag "/bids", method: :post do %>
     <div>
     <%= label_tag :bid, "place your bid "   %>
     <%= text_field_tag :bid %>
     </div>
     <div>
     <%= label_tag :event %>
     <%= text_field_tag :event_id, params[:id] %>
     </div>

      <div>
      <%= label_tag :user_id %>
      <%= text_field_tag :user_id %>
      </div>

      <div>
      <%= label_tag :lowest_price %>
      <%= text_field_tag :lowest_price %>
      </div>
      <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>

   <% end %>
```

here is my create method in my bids controller for the time being

```
    def create
    @bidd = Bid.new(event_id: params[:event_id], user_id: params[:user_id], bid: params[:bid], lowest_price: params[:lowest_price])


 if session[:user_id] == current_user.id
   @bidd.save
   flash[:success] = "bid created."
   redirect_to "/users/#{current_user.id}"
else
   flash[:warning] = 'please sign in'
   redirect_to '/login'
 end
```

end
and then here is my user/show page which is just @bidd in skull tags i know i need something like at @bidd.bid but im creating from my bid controller and showing on the user page so basically I'd like to find a way to display all the users bids on a user show page and also not have to manually enter the event id and current lowest price and user id to save a bid. also the the event id is being pulled from an api i thought first to make a userbid thru model but didnt think that would be necessary

```
       #<%maybe something like @ <% @bidd.each do |a| %>
          <p>event: <%= a.event_id %></p>
          <p>Price: <%= a.bid %></p>

    <% end %>
```

Comment: sorry if my title is not that clear I'm working on asking better and more direct  questions

Comment: would i change the bid form tag maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had a naming issue in my user show method

```
    def show
  @bids = Bid.where(user_id: current_user.id)
render 'show.html.erb'
```

should be
        @bidds
and

```
    <% @bidds.each do |a| %>
          <p>event: <%= a.event_id %></p>
          <p>Price: <%= a.bid %></p>

    <% end %>
```

worked to display that users bids now lets see if it can be done without having to fill in those params manually on the event show page.